# Bubble Sort in 16Bit Harvard Machine

Tags: algorithm, assembly

I'm currently working on a project that requires me to write a bubble sort algorithm in Harvard Machine 16 Bit Assembly Code. I tried searching for it online, however most assembly code snippets use the CMP and MOV operators.

I have the following instruction available:
ADD, SUB, AND, Copy, ADDI, SUBI, ANDI, LOADI, BZ, BEQ, BRA, SW, LW.

Could anyone please give me a nudge in the proper direction?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Why don't you use insertion sort instead? It is equally easy to understand and implement, but it is faster in most cases, and never slower. The optimization of chained swaps (which reduces the number of assignments to nearly 2 per swap instead of 3) is pretty natural in insertion sort, but quite difficult in bubble sort.

Comment: Hi, the assignment given to me specifies that I have to use bubble-sort (This would not have been my choice of sorting-algorithm)

Answer (score 2):

You can always implement an equivalent of `CMP` using `SUB` (or even `ADD` if `SUB` isn't available).

`MOV` can always be constructed out of a load and a store. You could also simulate it using a load and `ADD` to a zero-initialized register or memory location.

Don't search. Write the algorithm in pseudo-code and see how you can construct each step with the instructions you've got.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. I'm currently working on converting the following pseudo code: void bubblesort( int * a , int n ) { int temp; //for swapping for ( int i = 0 ; i < n - 2 ; i++) { for (int j = 0 ; j < n - 1 ; j++) { if ( a[j] > a[j + 1] ) { temp = a[j]; a[j]=a[j + 1]; a[j + 1] = temp; } } } } Could you give me a nudge in the proper direction? (I'm quite new to assembly code.

Comment: There are assembly tutorials online. If you encounter specific problems, ask specific questions. I'm not going to give a 100-hour lecture or solve the problem for you entirely. Do your part.

Comment: I also suggest writing and testing components of the solution. For example, array element swap is needed. Write a code fragment to do it, and test it separately.